# Rotational frames and Coriolis deviation

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, coriolis-effect

[image]

I have a question regarding a problem that is the deviation of an object due to the rotation of the earth ( cause by pseudoforces ). I've seen this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IMnhYEYZpc&t=1070s&ab_channel=DrBenYelverton, and I understood most of the steps to derive the deviation. However I didn't understand the geometric projection of the angular velocity vector that is in matrix form. Can someone here explain this projection and maybe generalize to other cases? Note: I understand rotational frames and its derivations ( to get coriolis aceleration, euler and etc.) but in this particular case I'm really having a hard time making the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to project $\hat \omega$ onto the three orthogonal axes shown below.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this helped my confusion